Adding a field into a visual in PowerBI Desktop
I have created a PowerBI report selecting a spreadsheet as the source. The spreadsheet is populated using power query into ADO with some additional calculated columns added.
I started adding columns into a visual on a PowerBI Page, however, when I select one of the fields from the Data panel on the left I get the following error message:

The column is clearly in the table so I can only assume that it has been found, and it may not be used in the expression, but I have no idea why:

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.
